# Overwriting/Replace/MITM/API Hook winapi.DeleteFile

Tags: python, c++, windows, winapi, api-hook

Sorry if this question has been asked before, I genuinely cannot find any information pertaining to this.

I will start by stating this assumption: When you delete a file on a Windows PC, the `win32api.DeleteFile` function is called.

Say you have a program/script/function ect that securley deletes this file for instance microsoft's `cipher.exe`, would it be possible to 'overwrite' native deletion method, and use your own? To the effect that any OS deletion would call your own function. I would aim to be able to do this in python, but any language would be accepted(I'm guessing C++).

If this is unclear please let me know and i shall try to clarify.

Thanks once again, stackoverflow!

Comment: This similar question has some answers that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910231/how-to-hook-c-in-explorers-rename-event

Comment: The assumption is wrong already: `DeleteFile` is the public API exposed in the Win32 subsystem to delete a file. Applications or drivers, however, could bypass that, and call the native API [ZwDeleteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566435.aspx) (or `NtDeleteFile`) directly. There are other ways to delete files, though, e.g. by calling [ZwSetInformationFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096.aspx) with a *FileInformationClass* of `FileDispositionInformation`.

Comment: `DeletFile` actually calls [`NtOpenFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567011) with `DELETE` access followed by [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567096). There's also [`NtDeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566435). A file can also be deleted by opening as `FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`  (Win32 `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`). Or via [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365539).

Comment: Ultimately these are all ways to set delete disposition in the file / link/ stream control block of the file system, which unlinks a file that's flagged for deletion after all handle and kernel pointer references are closed. So you should look into writing a [file-system filter driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548202) to add secure delete functionality.

Comment: For an example to get your started, see the [Delete File System Minifilter Driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/delete) on Microsoft's GitHub site. Also, if you want more insight into the design of Windows file systems, see the [fastfat File System Driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/fastfat).

Comment: You may be able to get additional help while learning and developing a filter driver on the [OSR lists](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=ListServer) NTDEV and NTFSD.